# Compare $(5/6)^4$ and $(35/36)^{24}$ without calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can anyone provide some hint how to compare $(5/6)^4$ and $(35/36)^{24}$ without calculation? Thanks!

After some transformation this question is equivalent to check if $(5/6)^{20}(7/6)^{24}$ is larger than one or smaller than one.

Comment: By compare what do you mean? You could do an analysis on the speed of convergence of $n/(n+1)$.

Comment: Are you asking for which is bigger?

Answer (score 22):

You are essentially asking whether

$$\frac 56 \ \ \ \ \text{  or  }\ \ \ \ \left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^6$$

are bigger.

Now by the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),

$$\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^6 = \left(1- \frac{1}{36}\right)^6 > 1 - 6\frac{1}{36} = \frac 56. $$

Answer (score 3):

Raise both to the power of $3\over2$. Then we will be comparing
$\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^6\;\text{ to }\;\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{36}$, and we might have heard a thing or two about the sequence $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$, which increases and converges to... well, that's not really important here, just note that it increases.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more easy to find which is bigger by dividing one from another.
Let

\begin{align}
E&=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4 \Big/\:{\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{24}}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
E&=\left(5^4\!\cdot\!6^{48}\right)\big/\left(5^{24}\!\cdot\!7^{24}\!\cdot\!6^{4}\right)
=6^{44} \big/\left({7}^{24}\!\cdot\!{5}^{20}\right)<1
\end{align}

Since $\,E<1\,$ we have

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4 &\Big/{\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{24}}<1
&\implies&&
\bbox[1ex, border:2pt solid red]{\;\:
\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^4 <{\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{24}}\;}
\end{align}

Comment: It should be $6^{48}$ instead of $6^{24}$....

Comment: Sure..thanks...(Y)

Comment: How did you know $E$ was less than one????

Comment: We can write 
$$E=[\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^5 *{\left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{6}}]^4$$

Comment: @SathinduUdeshJagoda how do you know that is less than one?

Comment: @SathinduUdeshJagoda how do conclude that $\,6^{44} \big/\left({7}^{24}\!\cdot\!{5}^{20}\right)<1\,$ without calculator?